# Using select and hover listener in openlayers 2 - hover change style

Tags: javascript, select, hover, openlayers, mouseover

I am having some problem with styling feature on mouseover. I am able to get event, but changing style simply does not work. For selection it does, but for hover/mouseover it does not at all. Can anyone please help me with that. Here is my code:

```
var map, vectorLayer, wmsLayer, selectControl;

window.onload = function() {

    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

    wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {
            layers: 'basic'
        }, {
            'attribution': 'Provided by OSGeo'
        }
    );

    vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("My Layer Name", {
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                strokeColor: "#ff0000",
                strokeOpacity: .7,
                strokeWidth: 1,
                fillColor: "#ff0000",
                fillOpacity: 0,

                'pointRadius': 30
            }),
            "temporary": new OpenLayers.Style({
                strokeColor: "#ffff33",
                strokeOpacity: .9,
                strokeWidth: 2,
                fillColor: "#ffff33",
                fillOpacity: .3,
                cursor: "pointer",
                'pointRadius': 20
            }),
            "select": new OpenLayers.Style({
                strokeColor: "#0033ff",
                strokeOpacity: .7,
                strokeWidth: 2,
                fillColor: "#0033ff",
                fillOpacity: 0,
                graphicZIndex: 2,

                'pointRadius': 10
            })
        })
    });


    map.addLayers([wmsLayer, vectorLayer]);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();

    vectorLayer.addFeatures([
        new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(10, 10)
        )
    ]);


    var selectControlClicks = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, {
        onSelect: function(feature) {
            console.log('select: number of selected features: ' + vectorLayer.selectedFeatures.length);
        },
        onUnselect: function(feature) {
            console.log('unselect: number of selected features: ' + vectorLayer.selectedFeatures.length);
        }
    });
    var selectControlHover = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, {
        hover: true,
        highlightOnly: true,
        renderIntent: 'temporary',
        overFeature: function(feature) {
            console.log('hover: number of selected features: ' + vectorLayer.selectedFeatures.length);
        },
        outFeature: function(feature) {
            console.log('hover out: number of selected features: ' + vectorLayer.selectedFeatures.length);
        },
    });
    map.addControl(selectControlHover);
    selectControlHover.activate();
    map.addControl(selectControlClicks);
    selectControlClicks.activate();

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eW8DV/80/

Maybe my hole approach is wrong, maybe I should use just one SelectControl ?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with the declaration of overFeature and outFeature.

Actually, while onSelect and onUnselect are template methods, designed to be overriden, overFeature and outFeature are not.
Overriding those methods cause the override of the default behaviour ( layer.drawFeature(feature, style); ).

Anyway, I'd suggest you to use events instead. Try with

```
selectControlHover.events.register('featurehighlighted', null, function(e) {
console.log('feature selected ', e.feature);
});
```

Also, I'm quite sure that you can use one single control instead of two, but not knowing what you're trying to do, I can't suggest you another approach.

Comment: You were right. Problem was with declaration of hover listeners. With your approach it works perfect! Thank you! I was thinking of using just one select controller, but it seems like not that easy if I want both hover and selection. What I want to achieve at the end is:
- have possibility to click on feature
- have a possibility to hover over feature
- have a possibility to programatically select a feature, and to be honest just to select it on the map without calling featureseleced listener (only if selection was done programatically). That is the hole scenario. Thanks again for your help